# FLUTTER Incrementar o restar una cantidad a un producto

Tags: flutter, dart, app, operador-incremento

Tengo este código de Flutter.

**Lo que necesito es que que añada productos por Botones de Incremento y Decremento**.

Actualmente, tiene una clase QuantitySelection y un metodo showOption. (Como se ve en fotos).

He intentando varias formas y códigos que he visualizado aquí mismo en Stack, pero supongo que la forma en que esta construido interfiere un poco con lo que intento hacer.

Si pudiesen ayudarme o encaminarme, se los agradecería.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../common/constants.dart';
import '../../common/tools.dart';
import '../../generated/l10n.dart';

.
.
.
.

class QuantitySelection extends StatelessWidget {
  final int limitSelectQuantity;
  final int value;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Function onChanged;
  final Color color;

  QuantitySelection(
      {@required this.value,
      this.width = 100.0,
      this.height = 42.0,
      this.limitSelectQuantity = 100,
      @required this.color,
      this.onChanged});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (onChanged != null) {
          showOptions(context);
        }
      },
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: kGrey200),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
        ),
        height: height,
        width: width,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(icon:  Icon(Icons.remove), onPressed: () { if (onChanged != null) {
              }  },),
              Expanded(
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    value.toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: color),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
               IconButton(icon:  Icon(Icons.add), onPressed: () {  },)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void showOptions(context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      for (int option = 1;
                          option <= limitSelectQuantity;
                          option++)
                        ListTile(
                            onTap: () {
                              onChanged(option);
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            },
                            title: Text(
                              option.toString(),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            )),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 1,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: kGrey200),
              ),
              ListTile(
                title: Text(
                  S.of(context).selectTheQuantity,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}
```

[image: Asi se ve, le añadí los botones que no lo tenia, pero no he logrado que funcionen]

[image: Y esa es la forma en que se muestra ahora]
.
.
.

He buscado la forma con setState (aunque no lo manejo bien) y una variable de incremento, pero la Class QuantitySelection, no consigo que me devuelva el valor y lo guarde, ya que el valor lo toma del "void showOptions".

Lo que quiero es que con los botones (que se ven en amarillo) poder subir o bajar la cantidad del producto a adquirir.

Comment: trata de reducir tu ejemplo a algo pequeño que podamos reproducir aquí y así poder ayudarte , divide y vencerás

Comment: Disculpen, ya modifique un poco la lectura, y reduje el código únicamente al bloque que hace dicha función.

Espero de esa forma la lectura sea mejor.

Comment: trata de crear un ejemplo sencillo, que podamos correrlo aquí, una vez q puedas reproducir tu error en algo más sencillo, podemos ayudarte, por ahora no podemos entender q tratas de hacer y menos probarlo

Answer (score 0):

para poder utilizar

```
setState(() {

    });
```

Tienes que utilizar un StatefulWidget y crear un estado de la siguiente manera

```
class MiClase extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MiClase createState() => _MiClase ();
}

class _MiClase extends State<MiClase> {

}
```

Una vez creado, podrás modificar valores a tus Widgets y flutter se encargará de actualizarlos mediante la función

```
setState(() {

    });
```

Te dejo el codigo de lo que entendí que necesitas

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

int cantidad = 1;
Color colorElegido = Colors.green;

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: QuantitySelection(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class QuantitySelection extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QuantitySelectionState createState() => _QuantitySelectionState();
}

class _QuantitySelectionState extends State<QuantitySelection> {
  final int limitSelectQuantity;
  final int value;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final Function onChanged;
  final Color color;

  _QuantitySelectionState(
      {this.value,
      this.width = 300.0,
      this.height = 42.0,
      this.limitSelectQuantity = 100,
      this.color,
      this.onChanged});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3),
      ),
      height: height,
      width: width,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  cantidad--;
                  if(cantidad<1){
                    cantidad = 1;
                  }
                  print(cantidad);
                });
              },
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  cantidad.toString(),
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: color),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  cantidad++;
                  print(cantidad);
                });
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos.